# Speaker Diarization gives result of two users as "Speaker 1" instead of Speaker 1 and Speaker 2 when both speakers audio captured on Mobile

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to get Diarization in my speech to text conversion output from an mono WAV file.

I need "Speaker 1" and "Speaker 2" differentiation from my WAV file which has two voices.

But transcription always showing Speaker 1 for both speakers. This happens when an audio record of two speakers speaks from Mobile interface. If one speaker from Web and another one from Mobile interface getting correct diarization with Speaker 1 and Speaker 2.

I am using Batch Transcription of Azure to get speech to text from WAV mono file.

[Azure Batch Transcription SDK sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/samples/batch/csharp)

Comment: Hi, We got a correct result from one of the very clear audio using same Mobile Interface.

Answer (score 0):

We got a correct result from one of the very clear audio using same Mobile Interface.